# I need to find a point "D" that lies on the line AB such that the angle between DA and DC is 90 degrees.

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d

I have 2 lines in 3d coordinate system AB and AC. I need to find a point "D" that lies on the line AB such that the angle between DA and DC is 90 degrees.

Next might be irrelevant information but:
A is position of a perspective camera.
B is the position where the camera is looking.
C is the position of an edge.

[image: Image Plane]

I'm making a 3d modeling a tool and I have to grab an edge and drag it in 3d space. To change the depth I'm going to use the mouse wheel which is nothing you just have to bring it closer or further to the camera. But I'm not understanding how to the horizontal and vertical movements according to the camera.

What is bothering me is that if the 3d point C according to the 2d view plane of the camera is (20,89) if I drag the mouse from (20,89) to say (30,50) what would the new 3d position be. My idea is to consider a flat screen in 3d on which C lies and the screen is parallel to the camera.

Comment: Find the midpoint of $AC$, call it $M$, draw a sphere centered at $M$ going through $A$. The other point where $AB$ meets the sphere is $D$.

Comment: Does this [image](https://i.imgur.com/aPp9aBd.png) capture the situation you are trying to describe?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Yes sir.

Comment: The camera image plane is perpendicular to the line of sight. So if point $C$ lies at the edge of the image plane, then point $D$ will lie in the center of the image plane.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Sir. I need to find the 3d point of that center.

Comment: The square represents the virtual image plane which can be arbitrarily fixed in three-space. The coordinates of its center are $(0,0,z_0)$ where $z_0$ is arbitrary.

Comment: Do you want the image of point $B$ to lie in the center of the image plane? Or are its image coordinates and the image coordinates of $C$ arbitrary? If so, the image needs to be redrawn.